# Where can I find large glass covered stir bars?

Tags: electrochemistry

I am looking to use a large stir bar, on the order of 100mm, that is not coated with any Teflon or PTFE. This is because my application is measuring PTFE in water and a stir bar can effect the results. I cannot seem to find one over 38mm. I would be willing to use any other material than PTFE/Teflon.

Comment: What about searching for longer but narrow rod/cylinder magnets and sealing them in a glass tube, done by glassware workers or using a lab gas burner?

Comment: The trouble is that magnets made of steel are not magnetic any more at higher temperatures than Curie point ($773$°C).

Comment: Why should that be a problem? The magnet would not be heated. Alternative is e.g. LDPE coating. // The question is rather if there is a big enough and strong enough stirrer and/or what is the expected length of the magnet itself. If the rotating magnet of the stirrer is too short, the stirrer may not be able to power the stirring.

Comment: You don't describe the setup in enough detail (e.g. container is a flat beaker, or round bottom flask, temperature/pH/composition of the medium). At larger scale, and especially for more viscous media, overhead stirrers are more efficient than stirring rods (without particular endorsement, examples of such a «[drilling machines](https://www.ika.com/en/Products-LabEq/Overhead-Stirrers-pg187/)», and [mounts](https://www.ika.com/en/Products-LabEq/Overhead-Stirrers-pg187/Accessories-cspacc.html), some can be manufactured of borosilicate glass, too). A 10cm rugby egg can shatter your flask quickly.

Comment: @Liz Be aware that what is being asked for often differs a lot from what is really needed. But what is really needed cannot be determined without detailed knowledge of the problem scenario.

Comment: Fisher Scientific have glass-covered stirrer magnetic bars up to 60mm  https://www.fishersci.co.uk/shop/products/glass-encased-stir-bars-3/p-8007716

Answer (score 1):

As @Poutnik states, it's very simple to make such a stirrer.

- Obtain one or more magnets (such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00LM0I3WE)) to make the needed length.
- Obtain glass tubing of appropriate inside diameter. Soft glass is easier to melt, but prone to shatter for large pieces due to thermal stress. [Borosilicate](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=4mm%20i.d.%20borosilicate%20tubing) glass can be melted with a propane torch, with patience.
- Cut the glass tubing about 15 or 20 mm *longer* than the magnet.
- Melt one end of the tube shut.
- Insert magnet, possibly wrapping in plastic wrap or paper to cushion it and to keep from sliding readily. Push it into the tube so that it is at least 10 mm from the open end.
- Melt opposite end shut. The heat should *not* affect the magnet, just 10 mm away inside the tube, because glass is a poor conductor of heat.

Such a stirrer would be more fragile than a commercial product, but is *far* less expensive, and can be re-sealed into another piece of tubing, if broken.

You might look at some classic book on lab glass work, such as [Bolas](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/32962), [Frary](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/30066) or [Shenstone](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/33941). Glass blowing (flame working) is useful in chemistry, and can create better equipment at lower price than can be bough commercially.

Comment: En route to check if there is a scanned copy of the references (there is e.g. an entry on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/handbookoflabora02bolarich)), I notice your link to the book by Frary ([this one](https://archive.org/details/gri_33125001402441)?) and Shenstone ([this one](https://archive.org/details/methodsofglassbl00shenrich)?) equally use the ink to the book by Bolas on gutenberg.org.  Unclear if intentional, or accidental, feel free to add the links to archive.org.

Comment: @Buttonwood, now corrected; all available *gratis* on Gutenberg. Thanks for catching those errors!